# Why does this partial application not compile?

Tags: scala

The following:

```
val add = (a: Int, b: Int) => a + b
```

gets converted to:

```
object add extends Function2[Int, Int, Int] {
  def apply(a: Int, b: Int) = a + b
}
```

while

```
val a1 = add(_: Int, 3)
```

gets converted to:

```
object a1 extends Function1[Int, Int] {
  def apply(x: Int): Int = {
    add(x, 3)
  }
}
```

But when I do:

```
scala> val a2 = add _
a2: () => (Int, Int) => Int = <function0>
```

And then call `a2`, it throws an error:

```
scala> a2(1, 2) 
<console>:11: error: too many arguments for method apply: ()(Int, Int) => Int in trait Function0
              a2(1, 2)
                ^
```

Why is this? Why does the following work?

```
a2()(1, 2)
```

Answer (score 9, accepted):

`add` is already a `Function2[Int, Int, Int]`. If you want `a2` to have the same type, then a simple assignment will suffice.

```
scala> val a2 = add
a2: (Int, Int) => Int = <function2>

scala> a2(1, 2)
res3: Int = 3
```

What you're thinking of is eta-expansion of a method into a function. If we had:

```
def add(a: Int, b: Int): Int = a + b
```

*Then*, we would use `add _` to get the eta-expansion to assign to a value.

```
scala> def a2 = add _
a2: (Int, Int) => Int

scala> a2(1, 2)
res4: Int = 3
```

But `add` is *already* a function, so the underscore has a different meaning. `add` is now a *value* and not a *method*. Since `add` is a *value*, it is like a *parameter-less method* that returns a `Function2[Int, Int, Int]`. And if we try to get the eta-expansion of that, we get `() => Function2[Int, Int, Int]`.

Consider a simpler example where we have a simple `val a = 1`. `a` is essentially the same as a parameter-less method that returns `1` (`def a = 1`). If I try to obtain the eta-expansion, I will get `() => Int`.

```
scala> val a = 1
a: Int = 1

scala> val a2 = a _
a2: () => Int = <function0>
```